# PHP Session ID issue

Tags: php, session

I have a site and something on the site will not appear until I refresh the page.

I found this in my code `session_start();` if I delete my PHP Session ID the thing on my page disappears again, it seems like this session needs to set on first page load...does anyone know how to do that?

By the way the thing that will no show up is a form, a GET form.

Thanks

Here is the code with the session

```
function wpsc_core_load_session() {
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION ) )
        $_SESSION = null;

    if ( ( !is_array( $_SESSION ) ) xor ( !isset( $_SESSION['nzshpcrt_cart'] ) ) xor ( !$_SESSION ) )
        session_start();
}
```

and he is what doesnt show up

```
<form class="product_search" style="font-size:0px !important;" method="GET" action="<?php echo $pp_url?>/" >
                <input name="product_search" id="wpsc_search_autocomplete" class="wpsc_product_search wpsc_live_search_embed .wpsc_live_search" autocomplete="off" style="padding:0px !important; height:25px !important; vertical-align:top;" />
                <script type='text/javascript' > /* <![CDATA[ */
                    jQuery('#wpsc_search_autocomplete').keypress( function(e){
                        if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
                            var url = '<?php echo $pp_url ?>'+'?product_search='+jQuery(this).val();
                            url = encodeURI(url);
                            jQuery(window.location).attr('href', url);
                        }
                    });
                     /* ]]> */
                     </script>
                     <input type="submit" id="button" name="button" class="searchBtn" value="GO"/>
            </form>
```

I turned on my Wordpress debugger and this is what came out

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/plugins/jquery-colorbox/jquery-colorbox.php:34) in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php on line 13

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/plugins/jquery-colorbox/jquery-colorbox.php:34) in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php on line 13
```

and this message appears when the form that is missing is there....

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /home/content/19/9468119/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/wpsc-constants.php on line 18
```

Comment: Could you add the code to the question, please?

Comment: -1, What? I've looked through your stack overflow history, and you can cleary put together a complete thought in sentance form. This question does not show that skill. If you rephrase, and probably show a bit of code, it will go a long way to getting an answer for you.

Comment: I apologizes for my lack of code earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one fundamental problem:

```
if ( !isset( $_SESSION ) )
    $_SESSION = null;

if ( ( !is_array( $_SESSION ) ) xor ( !isset( $_SESSION['nzshpcrt_cart'] ) ) xor ( !$_SESSION ) )
    session_start();
```

You can't access the session before it is started. Try starting it and then accessing it...

Also xor is a bitwise comparison...I'm not sure if that's what your looking for here, maybe `||` is.

> it seems like this session needs to set on first page load...does anyone know how to do that?

Normally first page load is denoted by the top of your script or whatever runs before outputting headers but since your new I'll just say at the top. Try putting it there.

Most likely you are receiving an error and got `display_errors` off as such you get a blank page I reckon.

Comment: im very new when it comes to this stuff....what I just put a session_start() before this code?

Comment: @user979331 Yea put right at the top of your script and it'll do it's job

Comment: I put it at top of my function and that didn't work....ill try to put a session_start() in my header

Comment: @user979331 Maybe you can show us a little more code? Also try making a test page of just starting the session and showing the form.

Comment: I ran a debugger and I will show you the error it came up with

Comment: @user979331 Since you using WP I don't think you even need the `session_start();` I think the session is a global var in WP

Comment: I do need the session because without it the form does not appear. There was another error that showed up when I refreshed the page the form is there...I updated my question

Comment: @user979331 It says that because you are trying to do the session twice. As I said WP has a session already. The first error relates to the fact that you are outputting something before WP has a chance to do its own sessions. Check `wpsc-constants.php` on line 13 what is there? Are you including anything before `wpsc-constants.php`?

Comment: line 13 was a session_start() now the error is saying line 17 which is also a session_start()

Comment: I commented out all the session_start() in wpsc-constants.php and now the form does not show up at all

Comment: @user979331 What error do you get now?

Comment: @user979331 It is dead hard to debug code when it's not in front of you and no idea of it's scope or size so really I can only go so far :) I am going to have one more stab though: so you have commented out all parts of session and you don't get an error for sessions anymore. Maybe you are getting an error for someting else?

Comment: there a few other errors, I am commenting them out to see what happenes

Comment: @user979331 Those errors might be genuine ones that need solving, commenting them out might break your code further.